# Syncfusion Scheduler datasource

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I have the following part in my javascript code, in which I want to use a variable that contains the information to fill the datasources instead of writing down the information. 
Is there a way I can do that?

```
...
resources: [
                {
                    field: "IdDepartament",
                    title: "Departament",
                    name: "Departaments", allowMultiple: false,
                    resourceSettings: {
                        dataSource: [
                            //{ text: "Sales", id: 1, groupId: 1, color: "#100000" }, { text: "Programming", id: 2, groupId: 1, color: "#199999" }, { text: "Human Resources", id: 3, groupId: 1, color: "#299998" }, { text: "Support", id: 4, groupId: 1, color: "#399997" }
                        ],
                        text: "text", id: "id", groupId: "groupId", color: "color"
                    }
                },
...
```

I generate the info to be shown on the dataSource by using ajax and save it as a javascript variable and show the info on the console.log, just to make sure I recieve the correct information.

**EDIT:**

I want to do something like this:

```
var departments = ({ text: "Sales", id: 1, groupId: 1, color: "#100000" }, { text: "Programming", id: 2, groupId: 1, color: "#199999" }, { text: "Human Resources", id: 3, groupId: 1, color: "#299998" }, { text: "Support", id: 4, groupId: 1, color: "#399997" });
```

And use that variable where I specify the dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to assign the variable which contains the information to fill the dataSource instead of writing down the information directly as shown below,

```
// variable with resource data information
var resourceData = [
                    { text: "Nancy", id: 1, groupId: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                    { text: "Steven", id: 3, groupId: 2, color: "#56ca85" },
                    { text: "Michael", id: 5, groupId: 1, color: "#51a0ed" }
]

resources: [
                  {
                      field: "ownerId",
                      title: "Owner",
                      name: "Owners", allowMultiple: true,
                      resourceSettings: {
                          dataSource: resourceData, // assigning the variable to resource data source
                          text: "text", id: "id", groupId: "groupId", color: "color"
                      }
                  }]
```